# Can't change the value with setValue until end of script

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have the following code and I'm trying to change `isRunning` in `endGame` function and after call `setHighScore` to add the value to an array.
The problem is that it doesn't change it until the end of the script, in the return from the `App` function where is already too late for my `setHighscore` function to be activated by the `isRunning`, therefore my 'game' ends and the array is null.

I don't understand why when I call `setIsRunning` the value doesn't change instantly. I put `console.log` and it clearly doesn't change it instantly, how can i change it in that function, or what's best solution to change it? Thank You

Any other advice would be highly appreciated, maybe if there's a better way to do things!

```
function App() {

    let tempKey = 0;
    const [scoreArray, setScoreArray] = useState([]) 
    const START_TIME = 5;
    //const INITIAL_WORD_COUNT = 0;
    const [text, setText] = useState("");
    const [timeRemaining, setTimeRemaining] = useState(0);
    const [isRunning, setIsRunning] = useState(false);
    const [wordCount, setWordCount] = useState(null);
    const textAreaRef = useRef(null);

    function changeHandler(event) {
        const { value } = event.target
        setText(value)
    }

    function wordCounter(string) {
        const counter = string.trim().split(" ").filter(word => word !== "")
        return counter.length
    }

    function startGame() {
        //console.log("start game, setting isrunning true!  ")
        setIsRunning(true)
        setTimeRemaining(START_TIME)
        setWordCount(0)
        setText("")
        textAreaRef.current.disabled = false;
        textAreaRef.current.focus()
    }

    function endGame() {
        setIsRunning(false)
        setWordCount(wordCounter(text))
                   console.log("before ")
                   console.log(isRunning)
        setHighscore()
    }

    function setHighscore(){
        console.log("in function highscore")
        console.log(isRunning)
        if(!isRunning){

            setScoreArray((initialArray) => [...initialArray, wordCount])

            localStorage.setItem('score', JSON.stringify(scoreArray))
         }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (isRunning && timeRemaining > 0) {
            const time = setTimeout(() => {
                setTimeRemaining(prevTime => prevTime - 1)
            }, 1000)
            //          return () => {
            //              clearTimeout(time);
            //         }
        } else if (timeRemaining === 0) {
            endGame()
        }
    }, [timeRemaining])

    return (
        <div>
            <TopBar />
            <TextArea textAreaRef={textAreaRef} isRunning={isRunning} changeHandler={changeHandler} text={text}/>
            <BottomBar 
                startGame={startGame} 
                timeRemaining={timeRemaining} 
                isRunning={isRunning} 
                wordCount={wordCount} 
                startTime={START_TIME}
            />
            <HighScores scoreArray={scoreArray} tempKey={tempKey}/>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Why not directly using timeRemaining to indicate game is running or not ?

Comment: I had in that array `timeRemaining` and `isRunning` and it still wasn't working. I will modify again instead of only `timeRemaining` to have both `[timeRemaining, isRunning]` to see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @Vo Quoc Thang You mean to use `timeRemaining ` instead of using the state `isRunning` ?

Comment: that's right. timeRemaining == 0 equals to  isRunning == false

Comment: I still get into the same type of problems. I'm missing something but I don't know what. Basically when I change a value in `useEffect` with `setValue`, I console.log right after and the value is not changed instantly. Is something wrong in this aproach? Ex: I set wordCount to 4, then I console log it and it's 0.

Comment: Unless my problem is this `Much like setState in Class components created by extending React.Component or React.PureComponent, the state update using the updater provided by useState hook is also asynchronous, and will not be reflected immediately.` My aproach was incorrect I guess Because I wasn't aware of this. Slo maybe this is the answer, i need to research another way of doing things